# GROUP BY query slower when the data is in JSONB vs JSON

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

In a Postgres 9.5 db I have 111K+ rows of data, and on the below group by query I noticed that there was a significant performance difference.

```
SELECT json(b)_object_keys(data) FROM 
public.big_data
GROUP BY json(b)_object_keys(data);

JSON (1 sec)


"HashAggregate  (cost=87267.47..87368.97 rows=20000 width=173) (actual time=1051.083..1051.087 rows=6 loops=1)"
"  Output: (json_object_keys(data))"
"  Group Key: json_object_keys(big_data.data)"
"  ->  Seq Scan on public.big_data (cost=0.00..59418.47 rows=11139600 width=173) (actual time=0.045..808.669 rows=668376 loops=1)"
"        Output: json_object_keys(data)"
"Planning time: 0.175 ms"
"Execution time: 1051.170 ms"



JSONB (6.2 secs)


"Group  (cost=4676148.26..4787265.77 rows=11139600 width=202) (actual time=5565.078..6483.272 rows=6 loops=1)"
"  Output: (jsonb_object_keys(data))"
"  Group Key: (jsonb_object_keys(big_data.data))"
"  ->  Sort  (cost=4676148.26..4703997.26 rows=11139600 width=202) (actual time=5565.072..6379.112 rows=668376 loops=1)"
"        Output: (jsonb_object_keys(data))"
"        Sort Key: (jsonb_object_keys(big_data.data))"
"        Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 13352kB"
"        ->  Seq Scan on public.big_data  (cost=0.00..59794.47 rows=11139600 width=202) (actual time=0.035..491.338 rows=668376 loops=1)"
"              Output: jsonb_object_keys(data)"
"Planning time: 0.173 ms"
"Execution time: 6496.109 ms"


JSONB + IDX (6 secs)

"Group  (cost=4676148.26..4787265.77 rows=11139600 width=202) (actual time=5882.089..6767.256 rows=6 loops=1)"
"  Output: (jsonb_object_keys(data))"
"  Group Key: (jsonb_object_keys(big_data.data))"
"  ->  Sort  (cost=4676148.26..4703997.26 rows=11139600 width=202) (actual time=5882.083..6664.084 rows=668376 loops=1)"
"        Output: (jsonb_object_keys(data))"
"        Sort Key: (jsonb_object_keys(big_data.data))"
"        Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 13352kB"
"        ->  Seq Scan on public.big_data  (cost=0.00..59794.47 rows=11139600 width=202) (actual time=0.338..806.472 rows=668376 loops=1)"
"              Output: jsonb_object_keys(data)"
"Planning time: 38.047 ms"
"Execution time: 6779.720 ms"
```

I'm trying to understand why this might be. On all my other SELECT queries the JSONB & JSONB scenario clearly are faster. It is just this case with the GROUP BY where the numbers are not making sense to me.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add  the execution plans generated using `explain (analyze, verbose)`. [**Formatted text**](http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name done

Comment: Those are plain explain outputs, not `explain (analyze, verbose)`

Comment: Is the column stored as JSON or JSONB ?

Comment: @Mokadillion yes. the JSONB queries were run on jsonb cast data. the JSON query was run on json.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes. sorry. updated

Comment: Your root cause for the slow query is: "Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 13352kB*" - you need to increase your work_mem. However it seems strange that this step isn't necessary in the JSON query. If the tables have **exactly** the same data I have no explanation for that.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - the data is the same BUT one data is cast as JSON data type...the other is JSONB. Could the sort be slower on JSONB because of the lack of statistics?

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/112610/why-is-a-gin-index-on-a-jsonb-column-slowing-down-my-query-and-what-i-can-do-abo

Comment: Does that mean the column is actually a `json`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes. The results that I posted that are under the 'JSON' EXPLAIN block are run on JSON data. The results that I posted under the 'JSONB' EXPLAIN block are run on JSONB data. The results that I posted under the 'JSONB + IDX' EXPLAIN block are run on index JSONB data.